# Firebase rules write/read

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

If i write `write: "auth != null"` who can write ?

Only the person which has my google account and password or all persons who have a google account?
I want to be the only one who can write to the database page but I can't change the rule to false.

If I write: `".write": "auth != null"` who can write to my database?

Comment: I've tried to fix your grammar. Please check if everything is correct (no mistranslations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frank said, only people who have authenticated using Firebase can write with this rule. If you have no way for users to sign up for your app, then you'd be the only one who can write. If you have users create an account, they're "authenticated" as well and can write. If you want to limit writing just to your user account, get your user id and use this rule where `MY_USER_ID` is your uid, or look into custom claims.

```
".write": "'MY_USER_ID' === auth.uid"
```

This assumes you want to write from some interface other than directly in Firebase. If you want to prevent all writing and manually upload/edit copy directly into Firebase, you can set:

```
".write": false
```

...which would prevent all *writes* from users anywhere, but which would still allow you to edit your data in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this rule:

```
".write": "auth != null"
```

Any user who is authenticated can write to your database. That means anyone who signs in with a method that you've enabled in your [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/project-8080059325282098184/authentication/providers) .

Comment: If i don't change standard authentication setting and in my app there isn't login form who can write? Only me?